# Overlay GIF to Image and export it as a video

Tags: ios, swift, gif

I can't find any library for this. Is there an easy way to overlay an animated gif on image and export it as a video? The same with how Instagram stickers work on stories.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

https://gist.github.com/powhu/00acd9d34fa8d61d2ddf5652f19cafcf

How to Use it

```
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "gif", withExtension: "gif")!)
let tempUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("temp.mp4")
GIF2MP4(data: data)?.convertAndExport(to: tempUrl, completion: { })
```

NOTE: Swift3 , You may or may not need to change :)

Comment: Thank you! Tried using this. Is there a way to edit the number of loop of the video before exporting? When I exported it it only plays 0.1 sec.

Comment: @DanmarkArqueza Sorry I don't have idea about this you may need to ask in github